# What 'cherry' means in git-cherry?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick, git-cherry

What is the meaning of the word *cherry* in [git-cherry](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry.html)?

---

Besides the fruit, I've only seem the word in the *cherry picking* expression (also present in git with [git-cherry-pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html)), that means selectively picking something (right?).

Doesn't look like to me that *cherry* in `git-cherry` is related to the fruit neither to *cherry pick*.

I'm Brazilian so subtleties of the English language are not quite so obvious sometimes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about A word's meaning; not programming.  Try English.SE.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker English.SE wouldn't fit because I'm not asking the meaning of the word cherry per se; I'm asking in the context of git (what it means **in that git command**). That questions makes sense only here.

Comment: Git didn't re-invent the word 'cherry', if that's what you're asking.  The meaning of the word 'cherry-pick' is best given on English.SE.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Note that in the question itself I state the cherry-pick word (there's even no edit in my question). But the word it's just plain **cherry**, that makes no sense. Well, at least it didn't make sense for me since I don't use the command alongside with cherry picking, it's just a way for me to check what I'm pushing (see answer comments). I learned that the purpose of the command in the end it is related to the command git-cherry-pick, that's why the word cherry (and then, after the answer, it made sense to me).

Comment: This confusion is a well known characteristic (and, for some, issue) of git; git reuses it's commands all the time and sometime it's not a so-obvious way (git checkout anyone?). In the end I'm fine if you want to close the question, I got it answered and I learned what I wished to learn. But note that this question would be not only completely off-topic on English.SE, but also impossible to answer without knowing git.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's called `cherry-pick` because the task is like cherry picking. You look through a bunch of commits (in a real tree, leaves and branches) and carefully select some of them. It's a delicate job the same way cherry picking in real-world is.

`git-cherry` *is* related to `git-cherry-pick`. `git-cherry` reports which commits do not exist in a branch. In other words, it returns which commits can be `cherry-pick`ed, i.e. which commits are cherries (so they can be picked).

Comment: So in the end it is related to cherry-picking. Not really obvious as with git-cherry-pick but that makes sense.

Comment: @talles, well, what you do in `git-cherry-pick` is to take a commits from another branch into your branch. With `git-cherry`, it shows you what commits in another branch are not already in your branch. While with `git-cherry-pick`, you pick cherries, with `git-cherry` you see the cherries ;) Admittedly, `git cherry pick` would have made more sense than `git cherry-pick` (i.e., as a subcommand rather than another command), analogous to `git branch name` vs `git branch`.

Comment: Ya, makes sense. Wasn't that obvious for me at the first because most of the time I use `git cherry` to check what I'm pushing (similar to hg's outgoing command).

Comment: @talles, hah, it never occurred to me to check what I'm pushing. I usually check what I'm fetching (before merge) and with `git diff`. It always seemed to me that what I'm pushing is ok, since it's my own local branch.

Comment: nice mnemonic trick. Maybe I'll be able to keep that in my mind now. :-)